# Button in email to change cell value in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am designing a ticketing system that runs through google forms and sheets. I want the agents to never have to interact with the actual sheet. I want to have a link/button in the email ticket where the agent can mark as resolved and the value in a cell in the sheet gets changed automatically.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and there are a couple ways to do it. I would suggest the below slightly different method than what your question asks (what if they accidentally click it!?).

Since you're already using google forms, I would send your people a link to another form that *confirms* a ticket should be closed. You code the link to pre-populate the ticket number to ensure that there's no human error in making sure they entered the proper ticket number.

See example to a form [here with a link that will](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScsg1tMDqjDt5yenXF7Vs8cCSm8m9R3Uxd7OPdMJMFwnw00nw/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.343017052=69092688) populate the form with a number from the link (I used your question #)

Once the user clicks submit, you can use that event to have your app script go modify your spreadsheet accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Can you help me with populating the field please. I am unable to find the form name when i inspect the page.